# How to use a GlobalAveragePool layer as the output of a model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am receiving this error when I am trying to build a model using the output from another model.

```
Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a Keras `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: <keras.layers.pooling.GlobalAveragePooling2D object at 0x7Somthing or another
```

What I am trying to do is to use a finetuned model as the base model and retain the whole thing using a different method (an SCNN instead of a CNN).

This is how I am declaring the model and where it goes wrong.

```
pair_base_model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('glb_avg_pool'))
```

And this is how I load my previous model

```
base_model = load_model('../input/base-model-reid/0.ckpt')
print(base_model.summary())
```

Which gives me this

```html
......... Whole bunch of other stuff
block14_sepconv2_act (Activatio (None, 7, 7, 2048)   0           block14_sepconv2_bn[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
glb_avg_pool (GlobalAveragePool (None, 2048)         0           block14_sepconv2_act[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 1502)         3077598     glb_avg_pool[0][0]               
==================================================================================================
Total params: 23,939,078
Trainable params: 10,980,862
Non-trainable params: 12,958,216
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupoid I was working on this a little too late and found something simple that I messed up. 
I needed to use the .output for the layer in order to get the output I cannot just call .get_layer(xxxxxxx) as this won't work

```
pair_base_model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('glb_avg_pool').output)
```

This is the working code.
Thanks for anyone who looked at this.